# Unable to delete first node of singly-linked list in C#

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a singly-linked list in C#. In order to delete a node, I have written the following code:

```
public void deleteNode(int value)
    {
        Node node = this;

        if (node.data == value)
        {
            node = node.next;
        }
        else
        {
            while (node != null && node.next != null)
            {
                if (node.next.data == value)
                {
                    node.next = node.next.next;
                }
                node = node.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to delete all nodes but the first using this. Why does `node.next = node.next.next` update **this** instance, but `node = node.next` does not?

Comment: Because `node` is a local variable?

Comment: @MatthewWatson But what about node.next = node.next.next?

Comment: When you change "node.next" you are actually changing a field in a node. When you change `node`, you are just changing a copy of a reference to a node. You probably meant to use `this.next = node.next;` However, somewhere you will have a root that points to the first node. It's probably *that* that you need to change.

Comment: @MatthewWatson i get you, i have been using just **this** instance. Also, using ```this.next = node.next``` instead of ```node = node.next``` doesn't delete any node.

Comment: @Voodoo, **this** is read-only right? ```this = this.next``` won't work

Comment: @VandanaChandola `this.next = node.next` this will not delete your first node.

Comment: @VandanaChandola May be you can declare a global variable like `head` in your class to get the first node reference every time and create your class reference in singleton manner to get rid of `this` to get first node reference.
Refer this if you need help : https://github.com/Shubham2007/LinkedListDemo